# Symfony2 - urls per locale

Tags: url, symfony, routes, locale

I am trying to set up a couple of languages in my Symfony2 project. Now what I need to do is to find out what's the best way (symfony2 way) to define one routing which can handle such URLs:

```
 /en/contact 
 /pl/kontakt 
 /fr/contacter
```

How could I define the route ?

Edit:

Please note that solution with common "contact" part is not enough:

```
/en/contact
/pl/contact
/fr/contact
```

And I want to have a "contact" part translated (inside the route, I don't want to use translation system on this level).
In few words I want to link "en" to "contact", "pl" to "kontakt" and "fr" to "contacter".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recently found something like that:
https://github.com/BeSimple/BeSimpleI18nRoutingBundle

It's pretty much what you wanted. Enjoy. :)

Comment: Looks like the solution, but does it meant that there is no official Symfony2 way of solving this?

Comment: You could declare multiple routings by hand

`contact_en:
    pattern:   /{_locale}/contact
    defaults:  { _controller: AcmeDemoBundle:Contact:index, _locale: en }
    requirements:
        _locale: en

contact_pl:
    pattern:   /{_locale}/contact
    defaults:  { _controller: AcmeDemoBundle:Contact:index, _locale: pl }
    requirements:
        _locale: pl`


But it's not elegant. You have to understand that Symfony is "only" framework, a platform to do such a things. :)

Answer (score 1):

[Localized routing](https://symfony.com/doc/current/routing.html#localized-routing-i18n) was added to Symfony 4.1:

```
# config/routes.yaml
about_us:
    path:
        nl: /over-ons
        en: /about-us
    controller: App\Controller\CompanyController::about
```

Comment: I think that the question should be updated and rate this answer as correct.